# Solicitudes ajax en Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Este es el código ejemplo de un controlador y el manejo normal (no AJAX) de un Request o solicitud.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
        //
    }
}
```

¿Qué debo hacer para que funcione también para solicitudes AJAX en la función `store()` ?

Si creo otra función `storeAjax()` , puedo incluirla en routes.php (con una nueva ruta asignada) y funciona, pero no es una buena práctica, pues tengo 2 rutas y debe ser la misma para ambas solicitudes.

Comment: De casualidad probaste algo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quizás esto te pueda ayudar:

```
if($request->ajax()){ }//procesa la peticion ajax 
else{return $view;} //retornas por ejemplo,una vista
```

En cuanto al `Routes.php`, no hay necesidad de modificar, lo que haces en tu JS es un request de tipo `GET`:

```
$.ajax(type: 'GET', ...)
```

Y procesas la petición, espero te ayude.

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza el siguiente ejemplo para crear una función del controlador más potente.

- Controlamos si la petición viene de una petición AJAX o no, y devolvemos una respuesta en JSON o un Redirect dependiendo del caso
- Uso de Try/Catch para capturar errores
- Uso de Log para el registro de errores

-

```
public function store()
{
    $data = [
        'name'  =>  Input::get('name'),
    ];

    try
    {
        $result = $this->repository->create($data);
    }
    catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
    {
        Log::error("YourController@store: register your error", array('created_by' => Auth::user()->id, 'message' => $e->getMessage());

        if (!Request::ajax())
        {       
            return Redirect::back()
                ->with('type_message', "danger")
                ->with('message', trans('web.error'))
        }
        else
        {
            return "{\"result\":\"ko\",\"error\":\"$e->getMessage()\"}";
        }
    }

    if ($result)
    {
        if (!Request::ajax())
        {
            Log::info("YourController@store: Created OK", array('created_by' => Auth::user()->id, 'result' => $result->toArray()));

            return Redirect::back()
                ->with('type_message', "success")
                ->with('message', trans("web.created_ok"));
        }
        else
        {
            return "{\"result\":\"ok\",\"id\":\"$result->id\",\"name\":\"$result->name \"}";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "{\"result\":\"ko\",\"error\":\"Hubo un error guardando\"}";
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de petición AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('my_route')}}",
        data: "name="+name+"&_token={{ csrf_token()}}",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(result)
        {
            if (result['result'] == 'ok')
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        },
        fail: function(){
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

Crea una ruta que apunte al metodo Store de tu controlador, que te servirá tanto para peticiones desde un formulario como para peticiones AJAX:

```
Route::post('/my_route', array('as' => 'my_route', 'uses' => 'YourController@store'));
```

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario implementar otro método.

Si no te funciona puede ser debido a que Laravel 5 incluye una validación del token CSRF, por motivos de seguridad, en todas las peticiones POST, PUT y DELETE. Debes incluir este token en la petición.

Puedes ver diferentes métodos para incluir este token en la documentación oficial: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
        Response->json($name);
    }
}
```