# Como enviar parametros desde mi vista blade a un Controlador - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5

Necesito enviar una variable en javascript a que esta en mi vista en Blade y enviar a un Controlador que este guardaría en la base de datos.
Pueden pasarme un ejemplo

Comment: Te recomendaría usar ajax de jquery, que es lo mas fácil de encontrar , lo otro es vue js , pero eso es más difícil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pueden ocurrir varias situaciones:

1) La variable forma parte de un formulario
Si este es el caso y si lo que quieres es que la variable se envie al momento de hacer submit, puedes agregar un input hidden y setear el valor de la variable con Javascript, así:

En HTML:

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="nombreQueSeEnviaraAlController" id="idEnHTML" value="">
```

En Javascript, después de calcular/obtener la variable:

```
inputDeVariable = document.getElementById("idEnHTML");
inputDeVariable.value = variable
```

2) La variable es independiente al formulario

Utilizar AJAX. No se si estes familiarizado con AJAX. AJAX permite enviar peticiones y recibir respuestas sin tener que hacer un request completo de todo el formulario HTML. Personalmente diría que son formularios "parciales" que se envian con Javascript y asi mismo trabajas con la respuesta. Aca una definición más formal (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Preparas tu controller para trabajar con Ajax: [Solicitudes ajax en Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101/solicitudes-ajax-en-laravel)

Y desde Javascript mandas envias la variable (https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-con-javascript-puro) o puedes utilizar jQuery también (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Utilizando AJAX el Controller recibe la petición como si se tratara de un formulario clasico HTML. Para leer los parametros debes utilizar el objeto Request de Laravel.